# Java Mutex | Thread : Current Thread is not owner

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

we are currently working on a university project where we need to build a parking garage where there are Producers who "park" the cars and Consumers who "remove" the cars from the parking garage. Each Consumer and Producer needs to live on their own thread and we also MUST use Mutex/Semaphores OR Lock OR Monitor to allow exclusive access to the garage. Our problem now is that we don't know how to access and notify consumers from the producer thread (and vice versa). When we run it, this error comes:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner
```

I have linked the source code below. Whenever the garage is empty, the consumer is "sleeping" (we think that means .wait() ) and if it was full before he took a car, he must wake up ALL sleeping producers. Also if the garage was empty before the producer took the car off, he has to wake up ALL sleeping consumers.

We have no idea if the way we approached it is correct or just complete nonsense. So if you have an idea or a hint, we would be very grateful!

**Consumer Class**

```
package prog;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    
    private static int PARKING_GARAGE_SIZE = 4;
    
    Mutex consumerMutex;
    Mutex producerMutex;
    Buffer<Car> carBuffer;
    Thread currentThread;
    
    public Consumer(Buffer<Car> carBuffer, Mutex consumerMutex, Mutex producerMutex) {
         this.carBuffer = carBuffer;
         this.consumerMutex = consumerMutex;
         this.producerMutex = producerMutex;
         //this.run();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Consumer lÃ¤uft");
        int counter = 1;
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Consumer-Schleife beginnt");
                    currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
                    String threadName = currentThread.getName() + counter++;
                   
                    //consumerMutex.semaphore.acquire();
                        consumerMutex.mutex.acquire();
                            System.out.println("Mutex acquired");
                            consumerMutex.WorkingQueue.add(currentThread);
                            System.out.println("Consumers consumes on thread: " + threadName);    
                            
                            if(carBuffer.full()) {
                                System.out.println("Buffer full. Wake producers. Parke aus.");
                                // wake producers
                                producerMutex.WorkingQueue.notifyAll();
                                System.out.println("Producer geweckt");
                                
                                carBuffer.pop();                            
                                consumerMutex.mutex.release(); 
                                consumerMutex.semaphore.release();                          
                                Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 1500) + 500);
                            }
                            else if(carBuffer.empty()){
                                System.out.println("Buffer empty. Go to sleep.");
                                wait();
                                consumerMutex.mutex.release(); 
                                consumerMutex.semaphore.release();
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println("Parke aus");
                                carBuffer.pop();                            
                                consumerMutex.mutex.release(); 
                                consumerMutex.semaphore.release();                          
                                Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 1500) + 500);                       
                            }
                            System.out.println("Consumer-Schleife zu Ende");                
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Consumer Catch-Error " + e.toString()); // TODO: error handling
            }           
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      System.out.println("How many producers:");
//      Scanner producerAmount = new Scanner(System.in);
//      
//      
//      System.out.println("How many consumers:");
//      Scanner consumerAmount = new Scanner(System.in);
//      
//      
//      System.out.println("The Simulation starts with "+producerAmount.nextLine() + " Producers and "+ consumerAmount.nextLine()+ " Consumers");
//      

        Buffer<Car> carBuffer = new Buffer<Car>(PARKING_GARAGE_SIZE);
        Mutex producerMutex = new Mutex();
        Mutex consumerMutex = new Mutex();
        
        Producer producer = new Producer(carBuffer, consumerMutex, producerMutex);
        Thread producerThread = new Thread(producer);
        
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(carBuffer, consumerMutex, producerMutex);      
        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(consumer);

        producerThread.start();
        consumerThread.start();
        
    }
}
```

**Producers Class**

```
package prog;

import java.lang.Math;

public class Producer implements Runnable {     
    
    Mutex producerMutex;
    Mutex consumerMutex;
    Buffer<Car> carBuffer;
    Thread currentThread;   
    
    public Producer(Buffer<Car> carBuffer, Mutex consumerMutex, Mutex producerMutex) {
        this.carBuffer = carBuffer;
        this.consumerMutex = consumerMutex;
        this.producerMutex = producerMutex;
        //this.run();
   }
    
    public Mutex getProducerMutex() {
        return producerMutex;
    }
    
    public void run() {  
        System.out.println("Producer lÃ¤uft");      
        int counter = 1;
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Producer-Schleife beginnt");
                    currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
                    String threadName = currentThread.getName() + counter++;
                   
                    //producerMutex.semaphore.acquire();
                    //System.out.println("Semaphore acquired");
                        producerMutex.mutex.acquire();
                        System.out.println("Mutex acquired");
                            producerMutex.WorkingQueue.add(currentThread);
                            System.out.println("Producer produces on thread: " + threadName);
                            
                            Car newCar = new Car();
                            if(carBuffer.empty()) {
                                // wake consumers and do shit
                                System.out.println("Parkhaus leer. Wecke Consumer. Parke Auto Nummer " + (counter - 1));
                                consumerMutex.WorkingQueue.notifyAll();
                                notifyAll();
                                System.out.println("Consumer geweckt");
                                carBuffer.push(newCar);
                            }
                            else if(carBuffer.full()) {
                                System.out.println("Buffer full, go sleep!");
                                wait();                     
                            }
                            else{
                                System.out.println("Parke Auto Nummer " + (counter - 1));
                                carBuffer.push(newCar);
                            }
                            
                        producerMutex.mutex.release(); 
                    producerMutex.semaphore.release();                
                    
                    Thread.sleep((long)(Math.random() * 1500) + 500);
                    System.out.println("Producer-Schleife zu Ende");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Producer Catch-Error: " + e.toString()); // TODO: error handling
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Mutex**

```
package prog;

import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.LinkedList; 

public class Mutex {  
      LinkedList<Thread> WorkingQueue = new LinkedList<Thread>();
      Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);  
      Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);
}
```

**Buffer**

```
package prog;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Buffer<T> {
    private final ArrayList<T> bufferStack;
    private int size;
    private int top;
    private final Object FULL_QUEUE = new Object();
    private final Object EMPTY_QUEUE = new Object();

    public Buffer(int maxSize) {
        bufferStack = new ArrayList<>(maxSize);
        this.size = maxSize;
        top = -1;
    }
    
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    
    public boolean full() {
        return top == getSize() -1;
    }
    
    public void waitForFull() throws InterruptedException {
        
    }
    
    public boolean empty() {
        return top == -1;
    }
    
    public void push(T item) {
        if(!full()) {  
            bufferStack.add(0, item);
            top++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error: Stack is full!"); // TODO: catch error and print it  
        }   
    }   
    

    public T pop() {
        if (!empty()) {
            T item = bufferStack.get(0);
            bufferStack.remove(0);
            top--;
            return item;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: Stack is empty!"); // TODO: catch error and print it
            return null; // TODO: is null the best option for a return here?
        }
    }

    public T peek() {
        if (!bufferStack.isEmpty()) {
            return bufferStack.get(0);
        } else {
            return null; // TODO: is null the best option for a return here?
        }
    }

    public List<T> getCompleteStack() {
        return bufferStack;
    }
    
    
}
```

**Car**

```
package prog;

import java.lang.Math;

public class Car {
    
    private int Platenumber;
    
    public Car() {
        Platenumber = (int)(Math.random() * 999) + 1;
    }
    
    public int getPlatenumber() {
        return Platenumber;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like *homework.*  And if this is the case, "your instructor should be the person you go to for help."  Perhaps many people in your class are having similar problems, and this is how an instructor realizes that more explanation is needed in a future classroom session.

Comment: What is the purpose of `synchronized(this)` in each of your two `run()` methods?

Comment: The exception almost certainly is thrown from `...erMutex.WorkingQueue.notifyAll()`. You are not using `notifyAll()` in the way it was intended. See [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()), and also see [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).